# When creating custom content editor (Editor tab) in sitecore, what the format of URL should be if I have desired aspx page in another VS project

Tags: url, sitecore, sitecore6, content-editor

When creating custom item editor in Sitecore(Editor tab), only required field is the Url, which will point to the .aspx page. Where this .aspx page should be added and what URL should I type. I've created a web application in Visual Studio and an aspx page with the desired functionality in it. This web application isn't related with my sitecore project. How to specify the URL to this page. Or should I add this page somewhere to sitecore project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `core` database, then in content editor go to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors` item. Create new folder item here if you like and inside create new item with this template: `/sitecore/templates/Sitecore Client/Content editor/Editor` (you can copy any existing editor item into your folder). You can set header, icon and Url (any url, absolute e.g. http://stackoverflow.com or relative e.g. `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/Media Folder.aspx`).

[image: editor in core db]

Now go to `master` database and set this editor in `Editors` field (inside template or specific content item)

[image: editor in master db]

I think you should move your `Page.aspx` inside sitecore project (in layout folder or custom one)
[image]

then url should be `/layouts/Page.aspx`

Comment: what URL should I specify if desired aspx page is in another Visual studio project, not related to Sitecore project. Should I just write a path to this file like C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project\Page.aspx. Or should I add this aspx page to some folder in Sitecore?

Comment: and thanks for detailed explanation, I just don't know what URL to specify and will it work if this page also use some functionality of another page in the same project?

Comment: I think you should put your Page.aspx inside sitecore project. Clean sitecore installation don't include *.csproj file but you can create it manually and include your Page.aspx inside this project.

Comment: should I add this aspx page to layout folder with code behind .aspx.cs or maybe the whole project? this page use some functionality of another pages in project

Comment: create visual studio project http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/09/Create-a-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-for-a-Sitecore-Solution.aspx   then you can add you Page.aspx and other references to this project. So you will have only one project finally. (you can have references for other projects if you like, but aspx pages should be in sitecore one)

Comment: BTW @User I recently got Sitecore certified and got some info regarding Sitecore development strategies in team - You should research on internet regarding *Site root* and *Dev Root*..